# How to map facebook authenticate users to roles using the asp.net RoleProvider?

Tags: facebook, asp.net-mvc-3, oauth

I'm trying to switch my site from the asp.net membership sql provider to using facebook connect to do OAuth single signon.  I'd like to keep using the role provider as it makes it pretty easy secure sections of my site by flagging the controller class or controller methods with the Authorize(Roles="...") attribute.  The site isn't live yet so I'll be completely ditching the Asp.net membership provider if I can. (keeping the roles and profile provider)

I've got the facebook connect logging the user in and I can get his info.  But how do I associate that with a role?

I'd like the system to automatically add a new user to the "SuperHero" role after he authenticates and authorizes my app.

Am I on track here?  Is there a better way to handle roles when using OAuth2?  I'd like to add other OAuth providers later.

An alternate approach would be to keep the asp membership, then when I user logs in through facebook connect, I could find his record and sign him in with aspmembership.  But that seems sloppy.

Some sample code would be great and I'd think others would find it helpful too.

thx,
Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this ime is to actually implement a FacebookMembershipProvider for yourself. That way it ties in to all the other providers naturally. The main downsides are a) a lot of code b/c Membership is a fat interface, and b) some cruft b/c it assumes you'll be doing passwords, etc, which obviously you don't need for OAuth.